# copy a site to another installation

Tags: database

Read this documentation https://drupaltraining.stanford.edu/node/111

But I was under the impression the sql database file has to be edited before you can do this?

"Before importing SQL file to new database, find and replace old URL and site name with new one." but I cannot find url or site name in sql file.

Comment: In any case, a question is only good as the answer and there is nothing wrong with filtering info from various sources.

Comment: @CharlieBunt A question on any SE site needs to stand on its own - that is to say, the bulk of your question cannot reside in an external resource. If that resource goes down, the question is useless. Remember, this is a Q+A site, not a support forum, so any question needs to be useful for future visitors, it's not just to get you an answer to an immediate problem you're facing. In future I'd recommend summarising the relevant parts of any external document into your question, and providing a proper, full description of the problem you're having. Otherwise downvotes will naturally abound :)

Comment: Have since successfully copied databases by just renaming them in drupal with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the old URL then you may do that before taking a dump of existing database:

- Search the OLD_URL_VALUE in the database from the phpmyadmin. (It may be possible that you will get no value in result, that would be the case when you have no hard coded value of your Old domain)
  [image]
- Build the query to replace the OLD URL something like:

  // Example: Replacing OLD_URL_VALUE (from the "body" column of the "node_revisions" table):
  update node_revisions
  set body = REPLACE(body, 'OLD_URL_VALUE', 'NEW_URL_VALUE')
  WHERE body LIKE '%OLD_URL_VALUE';

---

Alternatively you may try the [Backup and migrate module](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate): Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database and files or migrate a site between environments.

Also you can dump some or all of your database tables to a file download or save to a file on the server or offsite, and to restore from an uploaded or previously saved database dump. You can choose which tables and what data to backup and cache data is excluded by default.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr For the drupal6 I have faced this issue, specially with the files of tinymce module (containing the files path along with the domain)

Comment: Well, I don't use phpadmin just linux command line but I did open the sql file in an editor and nowhere could I see a URL so I'm just going to ignore it.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr I have migrated lots of Drupal 6 sites, and have routinely run into absolute URLs.  The Insert module + TinyMCE is normally the culprit.